# javascript hang when matching regular expression using IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I got a bugged regex `"\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*@"`
when it try to test whether it matchs a string

```
"ffffffffffb3ffffffffffafffffffffffabffffffffffc2ffffffffffa7e"
```

it will cause IE and Chrome hung up. But works fine by FF.

I found out that the "?" in the regex is not necessary. And it works find after I remove the "?".

But here is what I don't understand what cause the problem.
Here is some test

1. `"\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*"` works fine.
2. `"\w+([\.\-]\w+)*@"` works fine.
3. `"\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*@"` cause the problem

Anyone knows why? or it's just the performance between browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

In your third example, the `@` (which obviously causes the regex to fail) forces your regex engine to try all possible permutations of `\w+(\w+)*` (since the character class is optional). With a string of this length, the calculations would take longer than until the heat death of the universe.

[image: RegexBuddy Screenshot]

Firefox appears to have an iteration limit on regexes and will abort after about a million attempts, Chrome and IE seem to be a bit more stoic here.