# DataAnnotaion fails(freeze) on client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, data-annotations

I have ASP.NET MVC webpage where I use DataAnnotation to validate forms at client side. One of the view classes have a property that looks like this :

```
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Länken måste vara mellan 3 och 100 tecken lång")]
[Display(Name = "Länk")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?)?$", ErrorMessage="Länkgen är inte giltlig")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
```

In the view I use this code for the propertie :

```
@Html.LabelFor(c => c.Url, true)
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Url, new { @class = "tb1", @Style = "width:400px;" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url)
```

When pasting in a URL like this :

> http://95rockfm.com/best-voicemail-giving-play-by-play-of-car-accident/

The webpage will lockup and I can´t do anything on the wepage. If I however paste this in :

> http://95rockfm.com/best-voicemail-giving-play-by-play-of-car-accident

It works just fine.

These javascript file is included at the bottom of the webpage :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The exact same problem accures both in IE and Chrome. IE will however came back and say that a script took to long and a button to stop the script. But when switching input control the script will run again and look the webpage.

Im not using any custom stuff so why do I get this?

Comment: This phenomenon called [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). I cannot fix your regexp (I'm not good with them) to avoid this error but there are a lot of similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723667/javascript-hang-when-matching-regular-expression-using-ie-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116675/why-does-this-regex-make-chrome-hang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407870/javascript-regex-hangs-using-v8 Another article: http://davetayls.me/blog/2012/10/11/its-a-regexp-catastrophe/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` in regular expressions matches any character (and, in fact, this period is what matches the slash after the domain in your URLs). You need to escape it or put it in a character class, to match a period. Like so:

```
@"^(http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?)?$"
```

or so:

```
@"^(http(s)?://([\w-]+[.])+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?)?$"
```

If you don't do that, and the pattern cannot find a match, you have a nested repetition, with an exponential amount of possible combinations. As nemesv linked you in a comment, this leads to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). However, if you are matching a literal period inside the group, then each repetition of the entire group *has* to end with a period, and hence there is no exponential amount of combinations.

To see what "exponential amount of combinations" means, I'll just link to two former answers of mine (one from today, actually):

- [RegEx slow when not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940097/regex-slow-when-not-match/18941089#18941089)
- [Comparing speed of non-matching regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179030/comparing-speed-of-non-matching-regexp/13179439#13179439)

One more thing though, why your pattern fails (catastrophic backtracking is mostly a problem for failing matches): you require only a single character after the first slash. You probably wanted to allow an arbitrarily long path and query string, so add a `+` to that character class:

```
@"^(http(s)?://([\w-]+[.])+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]+)?)?$"
```

However, in general, why reinvent the wheel instead of just [googling for established URL regex patterns](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=URL%20regex).

Answer (score 2):

MVC already has URL validation using [`UrlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute.aspx):

```
[Url]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

If you are using MVC 4 it will also create an HTML 5 `<input type="url">` element.

The client side validation will use [jQuery Validation's URL rule](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L1021), which is still a regex, but a much better one (for example, it supports more Unicode characters).